# Columnar browsing interface library for hierarchical data using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a hierarchical data browser in my Rails (3.2.1) application. Looking for a some user interface library which resembles Mac OS X Finder's column view or columnar class browser.

First question is, how people call this kind of interfaces? I couldn't figure out.

Second question is, if there is such interface library. I'm trying to find jQuery based implementation but no luck.

Possibly, I'm using wrong keyword to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [hColumns](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mac-Like-Hierarchical-Data-Displaying-Plugin-For-jQuery-hColumns/).  It allows you to display hierarchical information as Columns just as OS X's Finder does.

[image: http://jquer.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/hColumns.png]

Comment: Thanks. this is I exactly wanted last year:) Now, I can use this for other projects:)

Answer (score 2):

With a little creativity you could do this with [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) The columns can be easily accomplished with some css and jstree even has an apple theme for the tree views. There are no out of the box solutions that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks. That's seems one of option -- I haven't realized Windows's explorer like interface as candidate --  but I'd like to have some multi-columnar interface (I want to minimize the use of scroll).